# Find the Area of triangle in the semi-circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the above figure, O is the centre of the circle.

If $\angle BCO=30 ^\circ$ and BC=$12 \sqrt 3$, what is the area of triangle ABO?

I worked like OA=OB=OC(radii of the circle).

So, $\angle OBC=30^\circ,\angle BOC=120^\circ$

$\angle AOB=60^\circ,\angle ABO=60^\circ,\angle OAB=60^\circ$

Triangle AOB comes to be an equilateral triangle.

How Do I find OA?

Please help.

Comment: Can you find a right-angled triangle and use Pythagoras?

Comment: You mean AC=2r,AB=r and $\angle ABC=90^\circ$ ?

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 2):

The ABC angle is a right angle, so $12\sqrt{3} \tan(30) = AB$ then $\frac{AB\cdot BC}{2}$ and you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AO=x$.

Thus, $AB=2x$ and since $\measuredangle BCO=30^{\circ},$ we obtain: $$AB=\frac{1}{2}AC=x.$$
Now, by Pythagoras 
$$AC^2-AB^2=BC^2$$ or
$$(2x)^2-x^2=(12\sqrt3)^2,$$ which gives $$x=12.$$
Can you end it now?